# How to get error message for checkbox below it for eloqua form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a eloqua form with input checkbox with liveValidation.
So the error message for check box come side to checkbox rather than below the checkbox and content beside it.

Tried multiple ways to solve this.

```js
var field2 = new LiveValidation(dom1, {
    validMessage: "OK!"
});
field2.add(Validate.Acceptance, {
    failureMessage: "This field is required"
});
```

```css
.LV_validation_message {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}

.LV_valid {
    color: #00CC00;
    display: none;
}

.LV_invalid {
    color: #8e0909;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'pp-sans-small-regular', Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.LV_valid_field,
input.LV_valid_field:hover,
input.LV_valid_field:active,
textarea.LV_valid_field:hover,
textarea.LV_valid_field:active {
    outline: 1px solid #00CC00;
}

.LV_invalid_field,
input.LV_invalid_field:hover,
input.LV_invalid_field:active,
textarea.LV_invalid_field:hover,
textarea.LV_invalid_field:active {
    outline: 1px solid #8e0909;
}
```

```html
<input id="field2" name="legalCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="check" class="legalCheckbox" />&nbsp;
    <span class="signupCheck">{@pre type="content" key="checkbox.message" /}&nbsp;
        <a href=https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/ua/privacy-full class="signupPolicy">{@pre type="content" key="checkbox.condtions" /}</a>
    </span>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't have any id `dom1` in the page and also you have used `dom1` in a wrong way. It should be a string like **`"dom1"`**.

Here your input id is **field2**, so use `field2` instead of `dom1`

***Stack Snippet***

```js
var field2 = new LiveValidation("field2", {
  validMessage: "OK!",
  onlyOnBlur: true
});
field2.add(Validate.Acceptance, {
  failureMessage: "This field is required"
});
```

```css
.LV_validation_message {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}

.LV_valid {
  color: #00CC00;
  display: none;
}

.LV_invalid {
  color: #8e0909;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'pp-sans-small-regular', Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.LV_valid_field,
input.LV_valid_field:hover,
input.LV_valid_field:active,
textarea.LV_valid_field:hover,
textarea.LV_valid_field:active {
  outline: 1px solid #00CC00;
}

.LV_invalid_field,
input.LV_invalid_field:hover,
input.LV_invalid_field:active,
textarea.LV_invalid_field:hover,
textarea.LV_invalid_field:active {
  outline: 1px solid #8e0909;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://secure.eloqua.com/Include/livevalidation_standalone.compressed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<input id="field2" name="legalCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="check" class="legalCheckbox" />&nbsp;
<span class="signupCheck">signupCheck</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

LiveValidation function contains a property called `insertAfterWhatNode`.

The [Documentation](http://www.makumba.org/hudson/job/makumba-documentation/ws/makumba-documentation/doc/libraries/livevalidation-1.3/documentation.html#LiveValidationConstructor) for LiveValidation quotes:

> **insertAfterWhatNode (optional)** - {mixed} - reference or id of node to
>   have the message inserted after (DEFAULT: the field that is being
>   validated)

1. Add an `id` to your `<span>` tag.
2. In your field2 definition, add the property `insertAfterWhatNode` after the `validMessage` and provide the your `<span>` id in there.

Your code should look something like the snippet below

```js
var field2 = new LiveValidation("field2", {
  validMessage: "OK!",
  onlyOnBlur: true,
  insertAfterWhatNode: "checkboxtext",
});
field2.add(Validate.Acceptance, {
  failureMessage: "This field is required"
});
```

```css
.LV_validation_message {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}

.LV_valid {
  color: #00CC00;
  display: none;
}

.LV_invalid {
  color: #8e0909;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'pp-sans-small-regular', Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.LV_valid_field,
input.LV_valid_field:hover,
input.LV_valid_field:active,
textarea.LV_valid_field:hover,
textarea.LV_valid_field:active {
  outline: 1px solid #00CC00;
}

.LV_invalid_field,
input.LV_invalid_field:hover,
input.LV_invalid_field:active,
textarea.LV_invalid_field:hover,
textarea.LV_invalid_field:active {
  outline: 1px solid #8e0909;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://secure.eloqua.com/Include/livevalidation_standalone.compressed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<input id="field2" name="legalCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="check" class="legalCheckbox" />&nbsp;
<span class="signupCheck" id="checkboxtext">signupCheck</span>
```